# When I try to open the file again the file descriptor (fd) is -1 and the file doesn't open in read only mode can anyone please explain why?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I first open the file with read write access then i write some stuff in it but when i open it again using read only mode the fd = -1 so my if statement doesn't run, can some please explain why it doesn't open again in read only mode?

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, i;
    char buffer[80];
    char str[50], ch;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    i = 0;
    ch = getchar();
    while(ch != '\n')
    {
        str[i] = ch;
        i++;
        ch = getchar();
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    fd = open("Test01.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    printf("fd = %d", fd);
    if(fd != -1)
    {
        printf("\n Test01.txt opened with read write access\n");
        write(fd, str, sizeof(str));
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        close(fd);
    }
    fd = open("Test01.txt", O_RDONLY);
    printf("fd = %d", fd);
    if(fd != -1)
    {
        printf("\n Test01.txt opened with read only access\n");
        read(fd, buffer, sizeof(str));
        printf("\n %s was written to my file\n", buffer);
        close(fd);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line,

```c
    fd = open("Test01.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
```

is missing the default access mode, the third parameter which is needed whenever `O_CREAT` is used.  This is a bug, and causes the C library to use some random number instead, often 0, which means "no access whatsoever to anybody".

That includes the user who created the file.  Therefore, any attempts to open the file will fail.

If you fix this, say

```c
    fd = open("Test01.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
```

where `0666` is equal to `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH`, or "read and write access to everybody".  This will be modifed by the current `umask`, which lets users decide what permissions their files get by default, by clearing typically write access from others (`S_IWOTH = 0002`).

Simply put, `0666` is almost always used here.  The exception is when creating scripts or executables, when `0777` is used, and when the data is assumed to be private, in which case `0660` (access only to owner user and group`or`0600` (access only to owner user).

Answer (score 1):

```
    fd = open("Test01.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
```

is incomplete.

The [full specification of `open()` is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (note the bolded portion):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h>
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `open()` function shall establish the connection between a file
> and a file descriptor. It shall create an open file description that
> refers to a file and a file descriptor that refers to that open file
> description. The file descriptor is used by other I/O functions to
> refer to that file. The `path` argument points to a pathname naming
> the file.
>
> ...
>
> `O_CREAT` If the file exists, this flag has no effect except as noted
> under `O_EXCL` below. Otherwise, if `O_DIRECTORY` is not set the file
> shall be created as a regular file; the user ID of the file shall be
> set to the effective user ID of the process; the group ID of the file
> shall be set to the group ID of the file's parent directory or to the
> effective group ID of the process; **and the access permission bits
> (see `<sys/stat.h>`) of the file mode shall be set to the value of the
> argument following the `oflag` argument taken as type `mode_t`
> modified as follows** ...

You need to specify the file mode when you create a file with `open()`:

```
fd = open("Test01.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );
```